# What is wrong with my stack implementation in racket?

Tags: functional-programming, stack, racket

I'm learning racket and new to functional programming and wrote the following code for stack:

```
(define stack '(0))

(define (push x stack)
  (set! stack (cons x stack)))

(define (pop stack)
  (let ((result (car stack)))
    (set! stack (cdr stack))
     result))
```

When I do

```
(push 2 stack)
```

There is no error.
When I do `(pop stack)` I get back 0.
What am I doing wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you are using DrRacket, use Check Syntax on your buggy code.  The code will colorize in a way that helps to see the way variables are scoped.  Hovering your mouse over the use of `stack` in the `set!` will display an arrow pointing, not at the global variable, but at the local variable, to help you see what thing is being affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a global `st` variable, but you are calling `set!` on local variables in `push` and `pop`.  You need to remove the `st` argument from your functions.  The problem might be more clear if you renamed the `st` argument to something else (like `stack`).

```
(define (push x stack)
  (set! stack (cons x stack)))   ; stack is mutated, but st remains unchanged
```

Comment: The problem is I need a global stack and I would like to do push and pop, what would you recommend doing to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using global state i.e `st` and passing `st` as parameter to push as well and that is causing the local `st` in push to be updated and the global `st` remains `'(0)`.

You can solve this by getting rid of the global `st` as shown below:

```
    (define (push x st)
      (cons x st))

    (define (pop st)
      (values (car st) (cdr st)))
```

Usage:

```
    (let ((stack '(0)))
      (define-values (v s) (pop (push 2 stack)))
      v)
```

Comment: If I do (push 2 st) and then do (pop stack) it does not work.

Comment: You need to use return stack from push as param to pop